# How to create a series of commands in shell, which will stop execution on error

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

My usual git workflow for deploying is the following:

[while on master branch]

```
git pull
git push
git checkout production
git pull
git merge master
git push
```

Would it be possible to create a function for executing all these commands, but if one of them returns an error (i.e. merge conflict), it stops right there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use && which will only action the following command if the previous command completed successfully. $? returns the status command of the most recent command.

```
function git_checkout()
{
 git pull && git push && git checkout production && git pull && git merge master && git push
 return $?
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting `-e` in bash will cause it to exit if it sees a non-zero exit code in the last command in a command chain.

```
#!/bin/bash -e
# or `set -e`
false
echo 'I will never run!'
```

Comment: The thing is that I would prefer it as a function, so I don't have to create a separate file for it. Thank you for your reply anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `ERR_EXIT` which will cause your script to exit on any error:

```
emulate -L zsh # do not change the environment outside the script

# If a command has a non-zero exit status, execute the ZERR  trap,
# if set, and exit.
setopt ERR_EXIT

cd /jhkljhlk   # <-- file does not exit and ls gives an error
echo "this will not run"
```